# Google Analytics: Track user usage and flow

Tags: google-analytics

Can someone help to query `Google analytics` to track a specific user behavior and usage pattern?

Currently I pass user id’s to GA as

```
_setCustomVar(2, 'id', id, 1);
```

This is session based.

But I am yet to master how I can utilize this to view usage pattern & behavior for the passed id. Say, I need to understand the visualization flow for one id or the page view count for that id etc

Rephrasing, **can I filter all existing reports for a specific id that I can select**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably use [Advanced Segments](http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=108040) to filter the reports based on your custom variable. However, unfortunately I think you actually might be [breaking the Google Analytics privacy policy](http://www.google.com/analytics/tos.html) by passing a user id to it.

Answer (score -2):

No way are you breaking Googles terms...the ID belongs to the website owner and does not disclose any information about an individual that would break in privacy terms.

http://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795983?hl=en

Comment: This doesn't answer OPs question.